# How can I retreive the cookie value (created in javascript) and display it on webage using Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies

In my Laravel application, I am trying to look at ways of passing data back and forth between javascript and the view, this lead me to create a cookie like below:

View:

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('js/cookie.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
@endpush

//Now we are further down in the view:
<div class="cookie" load="cookie(this)"> //runs my cookie function
    Cookie Display:<br>
    {{cookie('test')}} //this is the laravel cookie() function
</div>
```

In cookie.js file saved in Laravel project directory public/js:

```
value = 198
$(document).ready(function cookie(){

//testing cookie functionality
document.cookie= "test=" + value

});
```

Page div viewed in browser:

[image]

Output viewed in developer inspector under storage:

[image]

Might be kind of hard to see, but in the developer tools it shows the value of the test cookie as 198, I am hoping to see that value printed in the page for display to the user, but instead, the user sees test=deleted. So what is happening here, and why am I not seeing 198 if the developer tools are seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are just setting the cookie with that helper function and intead needs to grab it from the request in the controller:       $value = $request->cookie('name');